# Redirect to another domain if pattern matches - IIS7

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

Given this URL:

```
http://domain1.com/pdfs/file.pdf
```

How can I redirect `domain1` to `domain2` using the `pdfs/*` pattern?

I am trying to redirect `http://domain1.com/pdfs/file.pdf` to `http://domain2.com/pdfs/file.pdf`

I have tried:

```
<rule name="Publications" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" /> 
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll"> 
       <add input="{URL}" pattern="^pdfs/$" ignoreCase="true" /> 
    </conditions> 
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://domain2.com/pdfs/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.

```
<rule name="Publications" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^pdfs/(.*)" ignoreCase="true" /> 
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://domain2.com/pdfs/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```